# Stop Chrome from prepending protocol to IP addresses in address bar

Tags: google-chrome, copy-paste

This seems like a simple question to me, but I can't find the question asked anywhere, let alone the answer.

How can I **stop** Chrome from automaticaly prepending `http://` whenever I copy an IP address (if at all)?

There seems to be some logic in Chrome to automatically prepend `http://` whenever you copy an IP address. For example, open a new tab and type `1.1.1.1`. Now, select it all and hit `^C`. Now, open Notepad and paste it in. `http://1.1.1.1` is what gets pasted!

Now, theoretically speaking, I can see why they would do this, since Chromium tries to transparently do things for users to make browsing easier (a la omnibox), but this behavior is pretty much **never** what I want. I frequently find myself pasting `http://` somewhere erroneously, and then having to go and remove that.

I did also notice this happens with domains as well, so perhaps this is not just an IP address specific thing but some "feature" that applies to the entire address bar.

Is there any way to disable this "feature" that automatically injects `http://` into copy/paste strings? I don't need it, and indeed, I don't want it. On any actual page navigation, the protocol is already in the address bar, so I personally don't see the point anyways. I know this is Chrome specific, because Internet Explorer doesn't do this - there, what you see is what you get.

This is with Chromium 70, but I also just tested with a recent version of Chrome and the behavior is the same. So far, I checked `chrome://flags` and I don't see anything relevant there. This is probably too obscure a thing to be a setting anywhere else.

I ask because I (like others, perhaps) frequently exploit the browser as a de-formatter, as it's very easy to do CTRL+C, CTRL+T, CTRL+V, CTRL+A, CTRL+C, CTRL+C to strip the formatting of any arbitrary text from any program. Often this involves IP addresses, hence the question. Obviously this is not what browsers are for, but browsers like IE do this fine, and Chromium keeps throwing a wrench in things with this "feature".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's entirely reasonable that if you're using the browser's URL bar for something it's *really not meant for,* it'll sometimes do it in a way that you don't want.

One way to avoid this behavior is to have the omnibar switch from URL mode to *search* mode. After pressing <kbd>?</kbd> to activate the default search engine (or entering a custom keyword, e.g. <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> for Wikipedia) the omnibar will expect a search query as input and will therefore disable all URL-specific rewriting.

<sub>[Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1172/)</sub>